# Drupal Install Fails with Lando BLT

Tags: php, mysql, docker, drupal, lando

### Background & Setup

I am trying to spin up local development environment from drupal using this [Lando BLT Tutorial](https://thinktandem.io/blog/2017/12/09/lando-blt-acquia/) to do a proof of concpet/simple setup to see how it works and I encounter the following error.

I am currently using the following:

- macOS Big Sur 11.0.1
- Docker Desktop 2.5.0.1
- PHP 7.3
- Composer 1.10.19

### Error Output

I parsed the stack trace for easier readability

```
 [info] Sites directory sites/default already exists - proceeding.
 [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/private/tmp/drush_fwtkwh --database=drupal --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent -A < /private/tmp/drush_LyVjVm
 [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/private/tmp/drush_jEVO19 --database=information_schema --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent -A < /private/tmp/drush_Xugn6U
 [warning] Failed to drop or create the database. Do it yourself before installing. dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mysql
  Reason: image not found
sh: line 1: 71580 Abort trap: 6           mysql --defaults-file=/private/tmp/drush_jEVO19 --database=information_schema --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent -A < /private/tmp/drush_Xugn6U

 [notice] Starting Drupal installation. This takes a while.
/**
 * Database configuration.
 */
  [notice] Performed install task: install_select_language
 [notice] Performed install task: install_select_profile
 [notice] Performed install task: install_load_profile
 [info] Undefined index: value install.core.inc:2303
 [info] Array to string conversion install.core.inc:2303

In install.core.inc line 2307:
                                                        
  [Drupal\Core\Installer\Exception\InstallerException]  
  Database settings:                                    
                                                        
  Array
```

#### My attempts

- I have tried to use brew to restart the mysql, which if I remember was `brew restart mysql`.
- I have also tried `mysql.server start`.
- As well as a `brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb`. * when I run the `brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb` it get a usage error from brew.
- when I run `mysql -u root -p` I receive the following:

  ```
  dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
   Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mysql
   Reason: image not found
   zsh: abort      mysql -u root -p
  ```

How do I get around or resolve this error? If you would like more info please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems but just updated to Big Sur 11.1 and the latest version of Lando (v3.0.24). My specs, fwiw:

- Latest version of Big Sur (11.1)
- Latest version of Lando (v3.0.24)
- Latest version of Docker (3+)
- Composer 1.10.19

Not sure if this is right or not, but after all these updates, I didn't have luck using mysql in the container--had to use it outside of the container with Lando commands.

Comment: what version Drupal do you use? and what about php? Im going to check it all out later today and see what happens

Comment: Drupal: 8.9.11 / PHP: 7.3.25. Good luck :-)